# why does not IPv6 (RFC 4941) privacy work?

Tags: 14.10, security, ipv6, privacy

I've followed instructions on https://docs.menandmice.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6361024

It simply does not work, I have no Ipv6 starting with  2001::: , only the same as before.

```
andre@Loke:~$ sudo sysctl -a | grep tempaddr
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = -1
net.ipv6.conf.vmnet1.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.vmnet8.use_tempaddr = 2
andre@Loke:~$ sudo sysctl -p
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 2
andre@Loke:~$
```

Comment: You can expect a better answer, if you show us what addresses you actually got, for example by including the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of '/etc/network/interfaces' and output of the command 'ip -6 addr'  and 'ip -6 route'. Also you might send '/etc/resolv.conf'.

Comment: Am I right when I think you don't have any IPv6 address wich starts with a `2` or a `3`?  If not, you must get a global address first (which always start with these two digits).  You might get one global IPv6-network from tunnel broker HE, or by installing `gogoc`.  Both need registration to get an account.

Answer (score 4):

With IPv6 privacy extensions, you don't magically get an address starting with `2001::`. Instead, the starting of the IPv6 address will be the what you get from your ISP.

You'll still use the prefix of the IPv6 address that's been assigned to you. However, the suffix (the 2nd part) will be randomly generated, instead of being based on your MAC address.

If you run `ip -6 addr`, you should see that there are several non-`fe80::` addresses for your main interface. These addresses should have the same global prefix (typically, the first four parts of the address). If so, this means that IPv6 privacy extensions are working.

You can also identify by looking at the end of each IPv6 address printed with `ip -6 addr`. Any link local IPv6 address line ends with a suffix of `scope link`, each global static ends with suffix `scope global static`, each from SLAAC ends with suffix `scope global dynamic`, each private extension address ends with suffix `scope global temporary dynamic` and expired with `scope global temporary deprecated`.

Also, note that the `2001:db8/32` has been designated for use in documentation only.

Comment: Thank you , I were confused by nt seeing the temporary addresses with ifconfig eth0 , once I use ip -6 addr - I see them just fine

Comment: Global address starting with 2000::/3, and privacy extension only works on global addresses.

Comment: @Anders: erm...I never said that this was for link-local addresses, and mentioned that there should be several non-link-local addresses for the privacy extension to work.

Comment: They should all have the same prefixes, not just any randomly global prefix.  So if one doesn't have a proper global address, one can't have a privacy extension adresses.  And if you have a SLAAC address, you will get privacy anywau.

Comment: Good edit, I add one to your answer.  And if one look at the end of the line with global IPv6 addresses printed by 'ip -6 address', it should say it is global temporary address.  Doesn't sit with one desktop Linux computer so I can't give one example of a static, dynamic and temporary global address.

Comment: Here are the output from `ip -6 address` on a link-local address, which never should is used to connect to internet, only your LAN: `inet6 fe80::XXXY:XXff:feXX:XXXX/64 scope link`, where X:es are ffrom the MAC address and Y has the second bit set.  Here are a global, dynamic by SLAAC. `inet6 2001:ZZZZ:ZZZZ:ZZZZ:XXXY:XXff:feXX:XXXX/64 scope global dynamic` where Z:es are the global prefix and X:es and Y are same as the link local address. This can be used on Internet. If you set a static address, the 2:nd bit in Y should be zero (so easiest is to set Z, and ff:fe to zeros for static accresses)

Comment: The RFC4941 address should be like the that ends with `scope global dynamic`, but where the Y and X:es should be some random hex digits, except 2:nd bit in Y should still be one. And the prefix Z:es should be the same as in the `scope global dynamic` address.  The private ones end with `scope global temporary dynamic` for the active one and `scope global temporary deprecated` for the deprecrated ones that will not be used on out bound connections.